# Ionic PushNotification is not defined

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

I am trying to setup pushnotification so I can get the device token to later send push notifications on PHP.

I followed this tutorial https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push and I am still getting the error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined
```

I am testing on Chrome and Android device. Both of them same message.

Comment: Its hard to help you out if we don't know what your doing wrong.  Post some code.